# C# Do more threads speed up writing to console without interfering with one another

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I am currently working on a simple command-line program that has a pixel class and displaying it to console is the slowest part. Could I use multiple threads to speed up writing to the console?

thee Vector2D class only holds a x and y position. the equals function returns if its x and y is the same as the compared value

the pixel Renderer function looks a bit like

```
public Vector2D location { get; private set; }
public char pixel { get; private }
public ConsoleColor FG { get; private }
public ConsoleColor BG { get; private }
public int layer { get; private }
public int ID { get; private set; }


public void renderer()
        {
            foreach (Pixel pixel in GlobalPixels)
            {
                if((this.ID != pixel.ID) && (this.location == pixel.location))
                {
                    if (this.layer < pixel.layer) return;
                }
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(location.x, location.y);
            Console.ForegroundColor = FG;
            Console.BackgroundColor = BG;
            Console.Write(pixel);
        }
```

Would threading this result in pixels being placed in the wrong spot or color?

if not what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Read your code. You set the cursor position and then write a "pixel".  Now, think what would happen if you had two threads doing that without any locking. Thread1 might set a position, and then thread2 might set a position before thread1 could write the "pixel". So, no, that's not going to work. The best way to do this (draw something on a screen) would be to use a drawing framework (like Windows Forms or WPF), and not try to draw on the console

Comment: @Flydog57 that is why I asked `Would threading this result in pixels being placed in the wrong spot or color?`. I added that to make sure my understanding is sound. I do know those frameworks exist, but this is something im writing for a console as something to further my understanding of C#. This is my first project where i haven't dropped it in the first week.

Comment: So whenever you write a pixel, you check a global array to test if that pixel should be ignored? This is most likely the real cause of your performance issue. Sort your pixels, track the position / FG / BG yourself so you can avoid calling those Console methods if nothing has changed.

Comment: When you are working from multiple threads, you need to consider *atomicity*. If you can do everything you want to do in a single *atomic* operation, then you don't need to worry about threading.  But, what you are doing is far from atomic, so you'd need to *synchronize* your operations using something like a `lock` (which gets rid of any multi-threading advantage; and there is likely no advantage-only complication). @Johnwu's answer is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unlikely that multiple threads will result in much of an increase, because the `Console` operations are all controlled by concurrency locks that will cause the threads to throttle each other.

If you need to speed up console rendering, I suggest implementing a buffer (e.g. a `char[80,25]` or something similar) and writing your pixels there. When you are done writing the pixels, copy the entire buffer to the console in one go, in order from top to bottom and left to right. The console is much faster at writing lines in order and is slower when you have to use `SetCursorPosition` repeatedly.

Here's a simple example to get you started:

```
public class BufferedConsole
{
    private class Cell
    {
        public char Pixel;
        public ConsoleColor ForegroundColor;
        public ConsoleColor BackgroundColor;
    }

    static private Cell[,] _buffer = new Cell[80, 25];

    static BufferedConsole()
    {
        Clear();
    }

    static void Clear()
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < 25; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 80; col++)
            {
                _buffer[col, row] = new Cell
                {
                    ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black,
                    BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black,
                    Pixel = '?'
                };

            }
        }
        Refresh();
    }

    public static void Plot(int x, int y, char pixel, ConsoleColor foreColor, ConsoleColor backColor)
    {
        var cell = _buffer[x, y];
        cell.Pixel = pixel;
        cell.ForegroundColor = foreColor;
        cell.BackgroundColor = backColor;
    }

    public static void Refresh()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        ConsoleColor lastForeColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        ConsoleColor lastBackColor = ConsoleColor.Black;

        Console.CursorVisible = false;

        for (var row = 0; row < 25; row++)
        {
            for (var col = 0; col < 80; col++)
            {
                var cell = _buffer[col, row];
                if (lastForeColor != cell.ForegroundColor)
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = cell.ForegroundColor;
                    lastForeColor = cell.ForegroundColor;
                }

                if (lastBackColor != cell.BackgroundColor)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = cell.BackgroundColor;
                    lastBackColor = cell.BackgroundColor;
                }

                Console.Write(cell.Pixel);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.CursorVisible = true;
    }

}
```

Now just replace this:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(location.x, location.y);
Console.ForegroundColor = FG;
Console.BackgroundColor = BG;
Console.Write(pixel);
```

With this:

```
BufferedConsole.Plot(location.x, location.y, pixel, FG, BG);
```

...and when you're done, call `Refresh()`.

Comment: I added a sample `BufferedConsole` class to my answer to get you started.